# Difference of training steps or complete run through

Tags: tensorflow

on tensorflow.org in the beginner-mnist tutorial they train with 1000 steps, 100 examples. Which is more than the training set which only includes 55,000 points ? In the expert-mnist tutorial they train with 20000 steps, 50 examples.

I think the training steps are done, so that one could every training step make a print-output what loss or/and accuracy one got without waiting till the end or processing.

But could one also simply pipe all examples through the train_operation in 1 step and then look at the outcome, or is not possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Training on the whole dataset at each iteration is called batch gradient descent. Training on minibatches (e.g. 100 samples at a time) is called stochastic gradient descent. You can read more about the two and the reasons for choosing larger or smaller batch sizes in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/49528/57331) on Cross Validated.

Batch gradient descent typically isn't feasible because it requires too much RAM. Each iteration will also take significantly longer and the tradeoff often isn't worth it even if you have the computational resources.

That said, the batch size is a hyperparameter that you can play around with to find a value that works well.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. I ask this, because i try to train a real "robot", and every action takes time (e.g. 3 seconds) and so training is a little bit other than e.g. training pong. Where the computer could play many actions in 3 seconds.  So i  must save the observations already done, and then to build a model i think i could simply pipe them all through the training_op at once,  or?

Comment: @floboticsrobotics I would recommend that you initially train with a batch size around 100 until the model stops improving on the validation set. Then start training the same model again except with batch size increased/decreased by ~30-50% See if that improves the performance on the validation set compared to the initial batch size. Repeat until you find the batch size that works best or run out of memory.